# Program to find tracks with no Traktor hot cues

Tags: windows, music

I use [Traktor](http://www.native-instruments.com/en/traktor/) to place [hot cues](http://www.reddit.com/r/DJs/comments/1r5bb8/whats_the_difference_between_cue_and_hot_cue/) in tracks. I am looking for a program that could

- List all tracks contained in a folder (and its subfolders) that have no Traktor hot cues
- Preferably I would like to have a GUI that list all tracks contained in a folder (and its subfolders) and allows me to order the tracks by the number of [hot cues](http://www.reddit.com/r/DJs/comments/1r5bb8/whats_the_difference_between_cue_and_hot_cue/)
- Work on Windows 7
- Works at least with mp3 (FLAC is optional but preferable)
- Free is preferred
- With GUI is preferred